# Getting C2065 errors while trying to run a child process program In C++ using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, process

This is a simple program. its goal is to simply launches itself again, showing its system process ID and its location in the process list.
here is the Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void StartClone(int nCloneID)
{
   // extract the file name used for the current 
   //executable file
   TCHAR szFilename[MAX_PATH];
   GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFilename, MAX_PATH);

   // Format the command line for the child process 
   //and notify its EXE filename and clone ID
   TCHAR szCmdLine[MAX_PATH];
   sprintf(szCmdLine, "\"%s\" %d", szFilename, nCloneID);

   // STARTUPINFO structure for child processes
   STARTUPINFO si;
   ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
   // must be the size of this structure
   si.cb = sizeof(si);                            
   // returned process information for the child process
   PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

   // Create processes using the same executable and command line, and 
   //assign the nature of their child processes
   BOOL bCreateOK = ::CreateProcess(
     szFilename,             // The name of the application that generated the EXE      

    szCmdLine,                  // tell the flag that behaves like a child process
    NULL,                       // default process security
    NULL,                       // default thread safety
    FALSE, // does not inherit the handle
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,         // use the new console
    NULL,                       // new environment
    NULL,                       // Current directory
    &si,                        // start information
    &pi);                       // returned process information

// release the reference to the child process
if (bCreateOK)
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// Determine the number of processes derived, and the location of the derived process in the process list
int nClone = 0;
// Modify the statement : int nClone;

//First modification: nClone=0;
if (argc > 1)
{
    // Extract the clone ID from the second parameter
    ::sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &nClone);

}

//Second modification: nClone=0;

// Show the process location
    std::cout << "Process ID:" << ::GetCurrentProcessId()
    << ", Clone ID:" << nClone
    << std::endl;


// Check if there is a need to create a child process
    const int c_nCloneMax = 5;
if (nClone < c_nCloneMax)
{
    // Send the command line and clone number of the new process
    StartClone(++nClone);
}

// Wait for the response keyboard input to end the process
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

But When I compile it i get So many Errors, some of them are

```
Error   C2065   'TCHAR': undeclared identifier  OS_EX2-1
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'szFilename'        
Error   C2065   'MAX_PATH': undeclared identifier   OS_EX2-1
```

And In Visual Studio 2010 is working no problem. we just configure The " Character Set" proprety to "Not Set". 
Is there Any One who has an idea?? Thanks A lot

Comment: `pch.h` must be the first include. Every line above that is ignored by the compiler. Actually in this case its best to move `#include <Windows.h>` into `pch.h` anyways.

Comment: You could eliminate this issue by not using precompiled headers.

Comment: Agreed if this is a small project of a few thousand lines of source code with not that many external library dependencies precompiled headers are probably not helping you at all.

Comment: @drescherjm  yeah it's working. thanks a lot. Actually, I used VS2010 before but it's too old so  I upload to VS2017 in this month cause it has new features and easy to use. But I'm not familiar with it yet.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Ok Thanks